# How to prevent someone from forcing a change (w! in vim) to a read only file?

Tags: vim, chmod

Sorry for the newb factor but I just created a hello world file and then did chmod 444 on it.  I want to make sure nobody can edit its contents.

However if you use w! in vim, then you can override those chmod permissions and write something to that file.

Does the "!" have precedence over chmod?  How can I prevent someone from forcing a change to a read only file?

Comment: `w!` might temporarily change permissions to write, but only the owner and root can do that, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I just tried it with a dummy user, thanks =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the linux commond :

```
chattr +i yourfilename
```

that means you couldn't change the file or delete the file . I advice you to search lsattr and  chattr in google.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to chown it to a user they cannot su to. That way they will not be able to force it without changing user.